Using Orbital Rings to Achieve High Escape Velocity
Hoping an astrophysics-calculation-competent person could help confirm this scenario:
Say civilization has established an orbital ring around the Earth with an external launch track (using super-conducting magnets). Given that orbital velocity in LEO is about 7.8 km/s (17,500 mph) and our track can maintain double that speed, would it not be true that, once having accelerated some payload to double orbital V (=2*7.8 km/s=15.6 km/s), just prior to release (having successfully accelerated along the super-conducting track to 15.6 km/s) the centrifugal force experienced within the payload's frame of reference would be equavilent to Earth's gravity (1G) and that, upon release, the payload would travel away from Earth Orbital Ring at 7.8 km/s?

Orbital rings were defined by Paul Birch in 1982 as

A massive 'Orbital Ring' is placed in Low Earth Orbit (LEO); it does not need to bear large structural stresses, because it is in 'free-fall' everywhere except at the places where the 'skyhooks' deflect it. These 'skyhooks' ride upon Orbital Rings, supported electro-magnetically, and hold station above specific points on the Earth's surface.

His paper depicts a two-skyhook Orbital Ring System (ORS)...

It also describes a "Continuous Skyhook ORS"...


... composed of two counter-rotating rings and a geosynchronous sheath (Fig 11.); the sheath has to be supported by the inner rings and forms a continuous skyhook structure.


The central "roadbed" is suitable for accelerating vehicles along the ORS by linear induction motors.

He also talks about "Eccentric Orbital Ring Systems (EORS)" which he describes as

An orbital ring need not be deployed in a nearly circular orbit. It is possible to use a highly eccentric orbit, such as one reaching up to the height of a geosynchronous orbit and down to LEO. In this case orbital speed changes drastically between apogee and perigee; for the ring to remain stress-free it must change its specific length in proportion to its speed.

For this answer, I'm going to assume that your question is about accelerating a payload along the roadbed of a circular continuous orbital ring system located at LEO altitude by using linear induction motors.
With this design, there are two distinct linear induction motors and levitation systems. One is used at the skyhook-ring interfaces and the other is used to accelerate the payload along the geostationary roadbed.
So if you have accelerated a payload along the geostationary roadbed to the point that it is travelling at double "circular orbital" velocity (in the inertial reference frame) then the centrifugal acceleration would be roughly 4X "one gravity" (because $a = v^2/r$) and the gravitational acceleration would still be "one gravity". Within the payload's frame of reference, the combined acceleration would be negative three gravities.
Now since the payload and launcher are not on the surface of Earth, the "one gravity" we are using here would need to be defined as the acceleration of gravity at the altitude of the orbital ring. It will be slightly lower (perhaps 3%) than the 1G of acceleration experienced at the surface of the Earth.
So the statement

centrifugal force experienced within the payload's frame of reference would be equivalent to Earth's gravity (1G)

is not correct. The acceleration is actually slightly less than 3Gs and its in the opposite direction.
Also, upon release the payload would not be travelling "away from the Earth" at 7.8 km/s. It would actually be travelling parallel to the earth's surface at twice orbital velocity. At this point, the payload would be at the perigee of a hyperbolic orbit.
You can determine the hyperbolic excess velocity ($v_{\infty}$), which is the velocity that the payload will have when r reaches infinity, using some orbital mechanics. First calculate 'a' (negative semi-major axis of the orbit's hyperbola) using...
$${v^2 \over 2}-{\mu  \over {r}}={\mu  \over {-2a}}$$
Where 'v' is the twice circular orbital velocity, and 'r' is altitude of the ring plus the radius of the Earth, and $\mu$ is the standard gravitational parameter for Earth.
Then calculate $v_{\infty}$ using
$${\displaystyle v_{\infty }={\sqrt {\mu  \over {-a}}}\,\!}$$
I worked this out for an altitude of 300km and velocity of 15.6 km/s and arrived at a = -3218.217km and $v_{\infty}$ = 11.129 km/s.
So it would be more accurate to say that upon release the payload will be travelling alongside the orbital ring's geostationary roadbed at ~15.6 km/s (neglecting the speed of the roadbed due to Earth's rotation) and eventually (when r = infinity) it will be travelling away from the ring (and the earth) at around 11 km/s.
(Note that I did not account here for the gravity of the moon and, in practice, the payload will end up in some kind of an elliptical orbit around the sun.)

Great pleasure in seeing a fellow Birch fan online! Is there a tag on StackExchange for orbital rings? If not, I would certainly suggest having one as I remember reading somewhere (cannot remember exactly where) that raising 1kg to geosynch orbit with a correctly configured orbital ring would take 17kwH of energy. The cost of a rocket lifting 1kg to LEO is roughly 20000 dollars. Once an orbital ring in place (big given admittedly) there's no comparison (roughly $2 vs. $20000 or 5 orders of magnitude) and no propellant and no explosions...the ring providing optimal access to solar in space.

I added an [[tag:active-support]] tag. Hopefully anyone who takes an interest in orbital rings will also be interested in the newer concepts that also make use of active support.

Fantastic. Pleasure to see real progress to wit: StackExchange (thx to phil1008) now has a tag to discuss Orbital Rings!!!!! In fact it's already active and PERTINENT as the above comment where I state that cost/kg of reaching orbit with a correctly configured OR might be 2 dollars...well it turns out (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_ring#) it's more like 5 cents, or about 1kwH=2 hours of competition video gaming on a hyped up PC..precision so quickly found thanks to phil1008 and our new tag that everyone should check out. Great links to the relevant Isaac Arthur utubes to boot.

Your $2 figure probably is more accurate. The 5 cents figure from the 1982 paper was in 1975 USD, assumed 100% linear accelerator efficiency, assumed that we would be able to buy electricity at a cost of 0.005 USD/kWh thanks to space-based solar power, and only covered the cost of power.

The acceleration experienced by an object moving in circles is
$$a = \frac{v^2}{r} - \frac{\mu}{r^2}$$
A centripetal component minus a gravitational component. At orbital velocity, the two are equal.
Note how the centripetal component grows with the square of velocity, so  the centripetal component is 4G in your scenario, minus 1G for gravity, for a total of 3G.
1G of acceleration would be felt when your payload is moving at $\sqrt{2}$ times the orbital velocity of the ring, which just happens to be the escape velocity.
In your scenario, you are moving quite a bit faster than escape velocity, so your payload will have some velocity "left over" after escaping from the Earth,. This "velocity at infinite distance" $v_{\infty}$ can be calculated from the velocity $v$ and escape velocity $v_e$ like so:
$$v_{\infty}^2 = v^2 - v_e^2$$

You would indeed be travelling at 7.8km/s relative to the ring just after letting go. After all, that was your speed along the track. But rather quickly, the track would begin to curve away under you, and your own trajectory would begin to be gentry curved by the Earth's gravity. After a while, the question of relative velocity to the ring would start to matter less, as the point of the ring closest to you would be rather arbitrary, constantly changing, and measurements to every other part of the ring giving different results.

Thx. Fast and accurate. SE nails my error in "perceived" gravity at max acceleration (15.6 km/s) with the reminder that centrifugal force is a fonction of the SQUARE of velocity while phil offers a huge link to orbital ring theory (that's a keeper folks) and gives the theoretical framework for the effective escape velocity. Question though: how does one calculate μ for other gravity wells (sun, moon, jupiter, etc;)?

@C.Burns μ is the product mass and the Newtonian gravitational constant. Big table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter
